# [basic.start.main]/2 starts with "An implementation shall not predefine the main function". What does that mean?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

[[basic.start.main]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main#2):

> An implementation shall not predefine the main function.

What does this sentence mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A C++ program can have only one definition of `main` - the one you provide in your code. If an implementation defined `main`, you would not be able to provide a definition, as you would end up with a link-time error.